# Difference between 'apropos *' and 'apropos .'

Tags: regex, man

OpenSUSE 12.01, KDE, kernel 3.1.9-1.4-default

Trying to get all man pages. Basically the answer is `apropos .` or `man -k .`.  Why does `apropos \*` only returns about 300 man pages while `apropos .` returns close to 60,000 and in a lot less time?  I get that the former is doing a search and compare op and therefor is slower while the latter just belched out whatever it found. However, why does `\*` becomes a search operation while `.`, also a regexp, becomes a listing operation?

PS: apparently I had to type `\\\*` to get `\*`, interesting.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, try the following commands in a terminal:

```
echo *
echo \*
echo '*'
```

The unquoted/unescaped asterisk will be expanded before `apropos` gets it, and will thus do as many searches as you have files in the current directory.

`apropos '*'` is an invalid regex search; you'd need `apropos '.*'` ("match any character 0 or more times"), but that will give the same result as just `apropos .`.

Comment: Cool, I struggled with that for a while with my first bash script. Completely forgot. Thanks,